# Handling echo messages with multiple forms in PHP

Tags: php

Hi I've got my code similar to the following structure.

To put it in a simpler way, when I type some thing ('Hello World') on the text box and hit `One` it gives me an output as per what I've typed along with the message `form two is here!` and also the `TapMe` button.

Now secondarily (where the issue is) if I click the `TapMe` button the original text box output ('Hello Word') disappears. I need to keep it without loosing it on the screen!

Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one" style="width:300px; background:gray;">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1">
                <input type="submit" name="sendtwo" id="sendtwo" value="One">

            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="two" style="width:300px; background:yellow;">
            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
            {   if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
                {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;} else {echo $_POST['txt1'];}
            }
            if(isset($_POST['sendt']) || isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
            {echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!</rd></tr>"; 
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <?php echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='sendt' id='sendt' value='TapMe'></td></tr></table>";}
                if(isset($_POST['sendt'])) {echo "You hit TapMe"; return;}
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your text is disappearing because they're two separate forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You closed your earlier(same question), while I was making this code.

As far as, how I did it. Well, look up for `sessions` if you don't know anything about them.

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one" style="width:300px; background:gray;">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="text" name="txt1" id="txt1">
                <input type="submit" name="sendtwo" id="sendtwo" value="One">

            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="two" style="width:300px; background:yellow;">
        <?php   session_start(); ?>

            <?php
            if(isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
            {   if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
                {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;} else {$_SESSION['loged'] = $_POST['txt1'];}
            }
            if(isset($_POST['sendt']) || isset($_POST['sendtwo']))
            {if(isset($_SESSION['loged'])) echo $_SESSION['loged']; echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>form 2 is here!</rd></tr>"; 
            ?>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <?php echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='sendt' id='sendt' value='TapMe'></td></tr></table>";}
                if(isset($_POST['sendt'])) {echo "You hit TapMe";} 

                ?>


            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this and it works and my knowledge on sessions is I presume good enough to analyze this!:) Yea sorry I had to close the earlier cos I figured my explanation to the question was a mess! Anyways Thanks again mate!

Comment: can I also  ask one more question on the same? Now in this case it has to validate only txt1 value and assigned to a session. If I have a table instead, how do u suggest that I get that in to a session? is it possible if at all? Thanks

Comment: @DKarolis Everything is possible. You just need to make your question a little bit clearer.

Comment: well actually the example above looks at one single text box which is 'txt1'. Assume if I have series of text boxes which lies inside a table and dynamically populated how do I assign a session to that? Here its one single text box so you can do that but if I have a situation like I mentioned can u suggest me a method? Thank you

Comment: You can re-populate the if/else flows, by adding another sessions just like `if($_POST['txt1'] == '')
                {echo 'txt1 is empty!'; return;} else {$_SESSION['loged'] = $_POST['txt1'];}`